# How could I change this CSS to make the dropdown effect less buggy?

Tags: html, css

**I provided my CSS and HTML down below**. I am trying to finish off my dropdown, but there's an issue with it that makes the transition not so smooth. It's hard to explain with words on what it's doing.

I have tried changing the `display`, `max-height`, `padding`, and `margin` but there have been no results. Perhaps I need to add some JavaScript to it rather than CSS? Any suggestions or problems that can be pointed out will be great.

```css
#navigation {
 height: 100px;
 padding: 10px 3px 3px;
 background-color: #FFF;
 margin-bottom: 210px;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

#nav-container {
 display: table;
 margin: 10px auto;
}

#nav-items {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin-left: -45px;
 margin-top: -26px;
}

#nav-items li {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 width: 400px;
}

/* nav-dropdown */

#dropdown {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 width: 300px;
 height: 50px;
}

#dropdown p { 
 font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif; 
 font-size: 35px;
 letter-spacing: 5px;
 display: table-cell;
 margin: 0;
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: transparent;
 text-align: center;
}


#extensions {
 display: table;
 border-collapse: separate;
 border-spacing: 40px;
 height: 50px;
 width: 350px;
}

.label {
 font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif; 
 font-size: 35px;
 letter-spacing: 5px;
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
}

#dropdown-content {
 position: absolute;
 margin: 0 auto;
 opacity: 0;
  width: 300px;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: #C9C9C9; 
 border-radius: 8px;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 50px 0px white;
 z-index: 1;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 transition-property: all;
 transition-duration: 0.5s;
 transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
}

.nav-dropdown-container {width: 350px;height: 800px;}

#dropdown-content p {
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif; 
 font-size: 30px;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
}
#dropdown-content:hover {
 opacity: 1;
 max-height: 500px;
 padding-top: 1em;
   padding-bottom: 1em;
 margin-top: 50px;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
 display: block;
}

#dropdown-content:hover p {
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: 0.5s;
}

#dropdown-content p {display: none;}

#dropdown-link {color: white;}

#dropdown-link:link {
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#dropdown-link:hover {
 color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navigation">
   <div id="nav-container">
    <ul id="nav-items">
     <li>
      <div id="extensions">
       <div class="nav-dropdown-container">
        <div id="dropdown">
         <p class="label">TEST</p>
         <div id="dropdown-content">
          <p><a id="dropdown-link" href="hello.html">HELLO</a></p>
          <p><a  id="dropdown-link" href="world.html">WORLD</a></p>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You have not stated what is the desired effect you want to accomplish.

Comment: @MerakMarey my bad, I want the effect to smoothly slide down as I've attempted in my code.

Comment: The issue is coming from the `#dropdown-content:hover` selector: you are transitioning its position causing the cursor to enter/leave the element, leading to a paradoxical issue where it quickly flips between hovered and unhovered state. You will need to restructure your markup and/or CSS so that the hover event is bound to the label instead, which triggers the dropdown to appear.

Comment: Your problem is that there are multiple :hover "fighting" to act. When you hover over TEST, the drop-down start to appears, but because the mouse is there, it also hover over the links of the drop-down...that is what it cause the flickering...

Comment: @Terry Yes, I have tried something like that, by changing `#dropdown-content:hover` to `.label:hover`. The problem is, when I try to interact with the dropdown, it  goes away since my cursor isn't on the label element. I have yet to figure out a workaround to that.

Comment: @MerakMarey that doesn't appear to be the problem. I removed the other `hover ` selector for the label and it doesn't change.

Comment: TEST hover trigger the drop-down to appear, but then, since the mouse stays over TEST, it will trigger also the drop-down to hide, and and all over again...makes sense to you?

Comment: @johnboy13 Removing the other over does not affect the problem, you have to bind the hover to the ancestors...

Comment: @johnboy13 Basically the defect is hover status cycling...It's hard to explain, I hope you understand...a hover cannot be over more than one element at the same time, so triggering a hover will "hover-out" any other present in the page...

Comment: @MerakMarey Yes, I understand now. I apologize, I'm quite new to CSS and animations.

Comment: @johnboy13 Hey, no need to apologize, we all started somewhere, and you are a very good path my friend :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the reason is because when the `:hover` state is triggered on `#dropdown-content`, the mouse cursor quickly enters and leaves the element causing the state to be quickly toggled on and off repeatedly, resulting in a janky transition.

The fastest fix is this: you should change your selectors so that you bind the `:hover` state to the nearest common ancestor of both the label AND the dropdown content, i.e. `#dropdown`.

So you should change this:

```css
#dropdown-content:hover { ... }
#dropdown-content:hover p { ... }
```

...to this:

```css
#dropdown:hover #dropdown-content { ... }
#dropdown:hover #dropdown-content p { ... }
```

This is of course a **stop-gap** solution since I find your markup unnecessarily bloated in order to achieve a simple dropdown effect.

```css
#navigation {
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px 3px 3px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin-bottom: 210px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#nav-container {
  display: table;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

#nav-items {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: -45px;
  margin-top: -26px;
}

#nav-items li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 400px;
}


/* nav-dropdown */

#dropdown {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
}

#dropdown p {
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 35px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
}

#extensions {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 40px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 350px;
}

.label {
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 35px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
}

#dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #C9C9C9;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 50px 0px white;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
}

.nav-dropdown-container {
  width: 350px;
  height: 800px;
}

#dropdown-content p {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

#dropdown:hover #dropdown-content {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 500px;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  margin-top: 50px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  display: block;
}

#dropdown:hover #dropdown-content p {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#dropdown-content p {
  display: none;
}

#dropdown-link {
  color: white;
}

#dropdown-link:link {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#dropdown-link:hover {
  color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navigation">
  <div id="nav-container">
    <ul id="nav-items">
      <li>
        <div id="extensions">
          <div class="nav-dropdown-container">
            <div id="dropdown">
              <p class="label">TEST</p>
              <div id="dropdown-content">
                <p><a id="dropdown-link" href="hello.html">HELLO</a></p>
                <p><a id="dropdown-link" href="world.html">WORLD</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: @johnboy13 No problem. However, there is still a persisting issue where if your cursor is directly in the middle, the hover state on the first link will be active when the menu is shown, because the element will pass under the cursor. You should generally avoid the dropdown happening *over the top of the label/link*.